# Error vagrant up after set GetHostTimeDisabled = 1

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I wanted to stop time syncrhonisation on a Vagrant/virtual box VM. I ran this command:

C:\Users\User>”c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe” setextradata ENTER_MACHINE_NAME_HERE “VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled” “1″

As decribed here: http://www.activesplit.com/virtualbox-disable-date-and-time-synchronization-between/

But after that Vagrant up gives this error:

---

==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "7cc40a88-daf1-4088-a9c6-879fbf168cfd", "--type", "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Configuration error: Failed querying "GetHostTimeDisabled" as a boolean (VERR_CFGM_NOT_INTEGER)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

Process finished with exit code 1

---

Even when I edit the .vbox file and remove the line "GetHostTimeDisabled" the error keeps and the line is automatic placed back in the .vbox file.

Any ideas how to solve?

Comment: do you run VirtualBox Guest Additions ?

Comment: you can also try to run `”c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe” setextradata ENTER_MACHINE_NAME_HERE “VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled”` as far as I remember, it deletes the property if there's no value associated

Comment: @Frédéric Henri thanks, this solved the issue. Well I have still to disable time sync, but at least my VM is running again!

Comment: I think you have found the solution to disable the time already, but for those who have not, this helped me: https://superuser.com/questions/984040/how-to-disable-time-sync-with-windows-7-as-host-os-in-virtualbox

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can run the following command

```
c:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe” setextradata ENTER_MACHINE_NAME_HERE “VBoxInternal/Devices/VMMDev/0/Config/GetHostTimeDisabled”
```

It will disable the entry from the file and VM will start

If you're running Guest Additions, you need to disable it as Guest Additions is synching time automatically